# Field in required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse

I tried several solutions from this platform and other sources as well but none of them worked.

##### Application failed to start

Description:

```
Field userRepo in
com.pafproject.foodieapp.Service.UserService
required a bean of type
'com.pafproject.foodieapp.Repository.UserRepo'
that could not be found.
```

The injection point has the following annotations:

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Action:

```
Consider defining a bean of type
'com.pafproject.foodieapp.Repository.UserRepo'
in your configuration.
```

This is my main class

```
package com.pafproject.foodieapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FoodieappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FoodieappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my UserController.java class

```
package com.pafproject.foodieapp.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.pafproject.foodieapp.Entity.Users;
import com.pafproject.foodieapp.Service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("")
    private Users submitUser(@RequestBody Users users) {
        return userService.submitMetaDataOfUser(users);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{userid}")
    private Users getUserDetails(@PathVariable("userid") String userId) {
        return userService.displayUserMetaData(userId);
    }
}
```

This is my UserService.java class:

```
package com.pafproject.foodieapp.Service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.pafproject.foodieapp.Entity.Users;
import com.pafproject.foodieapp.Repository.UserRepo;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;
    
    public Users submitMetaDataOfUser(Users user) {
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }
    
    public Users displayUserMetaData(String userid) {
        return userRepo.findByUserId(userid);
    }
}
```

This is my UserRepo.java class:

```
package com.pafproject.foodieapp.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.pafproject.foodieapp.Entity.Users;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer>{

    Users save(Users user);
    Users findByUserId(String userId);
}
```

This is my Users class:

```
package com.pafproject.foodieapp.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

@Entity(name="Users")
public class Users {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String userID;
    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private String profileImage;
    public Users() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Users(int id, String userID, String userName, String name, String profileImage) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.name = name;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }
    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have this class: com.pafproject.foodieapp.Repository.UserRepo? I don't see any code for it in your question. Can it be autowired?

Comment: It looks like the repository bean is not registered in the spring context.

Comment: Would you please consider to tell us what you *have* tried to solve the pretty straightforward error message? You can't expect people to read a bunch of code without assisting to narrow the number of possible problems.